# Exclude existing files by name when copying with rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm executing the following two `rsync` commands. In the first command, I'm copying files from source to destination and in the second command I'm then checking the files and delete the files in source.

```
rsync --info=progress2 -r /local/data/ /import/myNAS/data
rsync --info=progress2 -r --checksum --remove-source-files /local/data/ /import/myNAS/data
```

I would like to only copy and remove files from source to destination which do not exists already in destination. I could do this using the `--ignore-existing` flag but with this flag files are copied when they are newer. I would like to have a check only on name and not timestamp. That means when a file with the same name exists in destination, the file should not be copied from source and should also not be deleted from source.

Is this possible?

Comment: Remove `--checksum`. Replace `-r` with `-a`. Discard the first of the two commands.

Comment: @roaima Why not using `--checksum`?

Comment: Because it's worse than pointless when both source and destination _look like_ local paths. Without it, `rsync` will just copy the files in their entirety. With it, it will checksum the files and then copy them anyway.

Comment: @roaima The source is a local path but the destination is on a NAS. My intention behind using checksum is that errors can occur when copying on a NAS (corrupted files).

Comment: `rsync` and the TCP/IP protocol already handle that. You've mounted the NAS into the local filesystem so `rsync` treats it as a local path. If you can `ssh` or `rsync` to the NAS server you'll get a far more efficient copy.

Comment: @roaima I see but is there no possibility for errors during copying? My intention was with the second command to check for copying errors.

Comment: If `rsync` returns non-zero exit status there was a problem. Otherwise you can guarantee the files copied correctly. (With one exception: `rsync` cheats for efficiency reasons, and only recopies if the size or timestamp has changed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description does not match how `--ignore-existing` should work.  It should indeed prevent copying (even newer) files that already exist on the destination.

```
$ rsync -a a/ b/
$ touch a/new a/update
$ rsync -ai --ignore-existing a/ b/
.d..t....... ./
>f++++++++++ new
$ ls -ln */{new,update}
-rw-r--r--  1 34570  344586812  0 Aug 17 14:50 a/new
-rw-r--r--  1 34570  344586812  7 Aug 17 14:50 a/update
-rw-r--r--  1 34570  344586812  0 Aug 17 14:50 b/new
-rw-r--r--  1 34570  344586812  7 Mar 26 17:02 b/update
```

`a/update` now has a more recent timestamp, but is not updated by rsync.

Can you try running your rsync again, but add the `-i` flag and show the output for your existing files?  It will add a line for the copied files for the reason it is copying. I'm wondering if there is some information in there that will point to the issue.

Comment: Thanks. You are right I think. But the problem now I have is that I only want to copy and remove files that are not existing. When I add `--ignore-existing` to the first rsync call then only files not existing in destination are copied but in the second rsync call then all source files are deleted. If I add `ignore-existing` also in the second rsync call then no files are deleted in source.

Comment: "existing" only lasts for one run.  Your choices are either a) do everything you need in a single rsync run or b) capture the files moved by the first run and explicitly sync/delete them in the second run.

Comment: I think b) is what I need. How can I capture files moved in the first run?

Comment: I don't know of anything official.  So I think you're left with either the `-v` or `-i` output and parsing it.  Either of which might be potentially (but unlikely) ambiguous due to newlines and such.